# adding braces to the negative values when subtracted

Tags: sql

How to add curly braces to the negative value, which will be the result of subtraction of two columns,

Suppose I have three columns

```
        A      B           result(B-A)
-----------------------------------------
        1      4             3

        2      1            -1 [should be displayed as (1) not -1]

        9      3            (6)
-----------------------------------------
total   3      5            (4)
```

How to do this in select query?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?  *FYI - This should be done in the application layer and not in sql.*

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: "Curly braces" are those: `{}`. What you mean is called "parentheses": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Answer (score 1):

If you use sql server try this :

```
select case  
       when (b-a) < 0 then  '{ ' + substring(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,(b-a)),2,2 ) +  '}' 
       else   CONVERT(nvarchar(max),(b -a)) END as result
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e879c/4)**

```
SELECT
t1.A,
t1.B,
CASE WHEN t1.B-t1.A<0 
      THEN '('+CAST( (t1.B-t1.A)*-1 as varchar(5))+')'
      ELSE CAST( t1.B-t1.A as varchar(5))  END AS result
FROM tbl t1
```

Result:

```
| A | B | RESULT |
------------------
| 1 | 4 |      3 |
| 2 | 1 |    (1) |
| 9 | 3 |    (6) |
```